# EXCEL VBA: How to manupulate next cell's (same row) value if cell.value="WORD" in a range

Tags: vba, excel

I want to change the next cell in same row in a if cell.value="word" in a range.
I have defined the range, using 'for' loop.
In my code,

```
if cell.value="FOUND THE CELL" then
cell.value+1="changed the next right side cell"
cell.value+2="changed the second right side cell"
end if
```

I know this is wrong. How can we do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
If cell.Value2 = "FOUND THE CELL" Then
    cell.Offset(0, 1).Value2 = "changed the next right side cell"
    cell.Offset(0, 2).Value2 = "changed the second right side cell"
End If
```